# Porque Ajax no me recarga el archivo?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax

Buenas a todos y gracias por adelantado.
Tengo una página en la que se genera una tabla con un id. En un "Evento Onclick" quiero que se borre y vuelva a generar esa tabla (via PHP), ya que debo incluirle el dato "Value" del "Evento Onclick", y no logro que me lo haga. Decir también que la primera carga de la tabla la hago desde un archivo.php, y la recarga desde otro.

```
function cargaCulturas(idCultura)
{
    $.ajax({
            url: "culturas.php",
            data: {cultura: idCultura},
            success: function( result ) {
                                            $("#descripcionCulturas").html(result);
                                        }
            }); 
}
```

Este es el código que carga la tabla en primer lugar.(funciona perfectamente).Es solo una parte del código que carga (donde se ve la tabla dentro de una "section" con un "id" asignado).

```
echo "<section name='listaOpciones'>";
        echo "<table class='botocult' id='tablaCulturas' style='float:left' 
cellpadding='5'><tr><td class='zoomIt' id='fisicas' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesFisicas('".$elemento['CULTURAS']."')\">";
    echo 'CARACTERISTICAS FISICAS' . "</td></tr>";
    echo    "<tr><td class='zoomIt' id='culturales' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesCulturales('".$elemento['CULTURAS']."')\">"; 
    echo 'CARACTERISTICAS CULTURALES' . "</td></tr>";
    echo    "<tr><td class='zoomIt' id='otros' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesOtros('".$elemento['CULTURAS']."')\">";
    echo 'OTROS FACTORES' . "</td></tr>";
    echo    "<tr><td class='zoomIt' id='iniciales' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesIniciales('".$elemento['CULTURAS']."')\">";
    echo 'OPCIONES INICIALES' . "</td></tr>";
    echo    "<tr><td class='zoomIt' id='historial' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesHistorial('".$elemento['CULTURAS']."')\">";
    echo 'OPCIONES DE HISTORIAL' . "</td></tr></table>";
    echo "</section>";
```

Este es el código que tendría que primero borrar y luego reescribir la tabla. La borra bien, pero no lo reescribe.

```
function cargaOpciones(idCult)
    {
    tabla = document.getElementById("tablaCulturas");   
        if (!tabla){
                alert("El elemento selecionado no existe");
        } else 
        {
                padre = tabla.parentNode;
                padre.removeChild(tabla);
        }

$.ajax({
            url: "opciones.php",
            data: {cult: idCult},
            success: function( result ) {

$("#listaOpciones").html(result);
                                        }
            });         
    }
```

Y este el código del archivo opciones.php

```
<?php
$cultura=$_GET["cult"];

echo "<table class='botocult' id='tablaCulturas' style='float:left' 
cellpadding='5'><tr><td class='zoomIt' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesFisicas('".$cultura."')\">";
echo "CARACTERISTICAS FISICAS" . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td class='zoomIt' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesCulturales('".$cultura."')\">"; 
echo "CARACTERISTICAS CULTURALES" . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td class='zoomIt' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesOtros('".$cultura."')\">";
echo "OTROS FACTORES" . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td class='zoomIt' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesIniciales('".$cultura."')\">";
echo "OPCIONES INICIALES" . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td class='zoomIt' 
onclick=\"cargaOpcionesHistorial('".$cultura."')\">";
echo "OPCIONES DE HISTORIAL" . "</td></tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué mandas la segunda llamada al servidor si no necesitas realmente datos del servidor en esa segunda llamada? Si explicas mejor el contexto quizá podemos ayudarte mejor. Si los datos de la segunda tabla están en el cliente no tiene sentido la llamada a `opciones.php`

Comment: Básicamente porque no tengo mucha idea, y pensaba que así sólo sería copiar y pegar lo que ya tenía, pero no funciona. También intenté recargar directamente con javascript haciendo un "document.getElementById("listaOpciones").innerHTML = "opciones.php"; y tampoco funcionó

Comment: Explica mejor las cosas porque creo que la solución es muy simple. Pero no entiendo por qué tienes que hacer dos llamadas, qué significa `$cultura` en esa segunda llamada, cuál es el criterio para re-escribir la tabla una segunda vez, etc.

Comment: La primera vez que se carga la tabla me falta una variable, al hacer onclick se genera esa variable, por eso la recarga. Y esa variable es la que recupera el archivo opciones.php con nombre $cultura, y implementa en la tabla. Supongo que se podía hacer con Javascript directamente sin tener que recurrir a php, pero yo no sé hacerlo. Ya he intentado que me escribiera algo con el metodo getelementbyid y el innerHTML, como he dicho antes, y tampoco me funcionaba.

Answer (score 0):

No existe el elemento `$("#listaOpciones")`. Fíjate que tienes

```
<section name='listaOpciones'>
```

Debiera ser, en cambio:

```
<section id='listaOpciones'>
```